# ath11k_pci: failed to connect to HTT: -110

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, network-interface, kernel-modules

I have Qualcomm QCNFA765 wifi card.
I am using custom-compiled kernel 6.1.55 and I have ath11k_pci in the kernel, and all firmware files are loaded successfully. Yet, when booting, I see on the console:

```
ath11k_pci: Service connect timeout
ath11k_pci: failed to connect to HTT: -110
ath11k_pci: failed to start core: -110
```

and the network device wlan0 does not exist.

But lspci -v shows the network card, and module it is using.

and dmesg | grep ath11k

```
ath11k_pci: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x90600000-0x907fffff 64bit]
ath11k_pci: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
ath11k_pci: MSI vectors: 1
ath11k_pci: wcn6855 hw2.1
ath11k_pci: chip_id 0x12 chip_family 0xb board_id 0xff soc_id 0x400c1211
ath11k_pci: fw_version 0x11090c35 fw_build_timestamp 2022-04-18 20:23 fw_build_id WLAN.HSP.1.1-03125-QCAHSPSWPL_V1_V2_SILICONZ_LITE-3.6510.9
ath11k_pci: leaving PCI ASPM disabled to avoid MHI M2 problems
ath11k_pci: failed to receive control response completion, polling..
ath11k_pci: Service connect timeout
ath11k_pci: failed to connect to HTT: -110
ath11k_pci: failed to start core: -110
ath11k_pci: ignore reset dev flags 0x4000
ath11k_pci: ignore reset dev flags 0x4000
ath11k_pci: failed to wait wlan mode request (mode 4): -110
ath11k_pci: qmi failed to send wlan mode off: -110
```

since I am using custom kernel, it is possible i am missing some kernel option. [Here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQk4VZEg) is my kernel config.

Also, I have booted Debian Live CD and the wifi card works fine there. So I can exclude any HW problem.